# After making actionbar smaller, navigation drawer toggle doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I had an action bar with a toggle that worked, but for some reason every time I changed the color of the action bar, the color of the entire page changed.  I figured out that this was because the action bar was taking up the entire screen.  I made some fixes to that (moved the action bar into a larger linear layout instead of keeping it in the drawer layout itself), but now since taking care of that, the toggle no longer works, and this is probably related, but when I drag the navigation drawer out, it hangs for a second, and I have to pull it from there.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**mainactivity.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import me.paxana.alerta.adapter.SlidingMenuAdapter;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment1;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment2;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment3;
import me.paxana.alerta.model.ItemSlideMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<ItemSlideMenu> listSliding;
    private SlidingMenuAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listViewSliding;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            //check to see if user is logged in
            if (currentUser == null) {
                navigateToLogin();  //if not, send them to the login page
            }

        else {  //if they are, send the username to the log (debug only)
                Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
            }

        listViewSliding = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listSliding = new ArrayList<>();
        //add item for sliding list
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Map"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_about, "Emergency Call"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_account_plus_black_48dp, "Friends"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_logout_black_48dp, "Log Out"));

        adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(this, listSliding);
        listViewSliding.setAdapter(adapter);

        //display icon to open/close slider
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //item selected
        listViewSliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
        //close menu
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
        //handle on item click
        //at some point it may make sense to change this to sort by item ID instead of position
        listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 3) {
                    ParseUser.logOut();
                    navigateToLogin();
                } else {

                    //replace fragment
                    replaceFragment(position);
                    //item selected
                    listViewSliding.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    //close menu
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
                }
            }

        });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    private void navigateToLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        //these flags remove the mainactivity from the history, so you can't back your way into mainactivity from the login screen
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
//create method replace fragment
    private void replaceFragment(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        }
        if(null != fragment) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context="me.paxana.alerta.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_sliding_menu"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled mike's answer and found what I needed to do.  I added

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I had deleted this code when I got rid of the overflow menu.

Comment: no need to be sorry, I really appreciate your help!  If you feel like putting up an answer later I'll give the best answer to you